# Spring Boot 2 - Webflux - Websocket - Netty - Compression

Tags: websocket, compression, netty

I'm using

- spring-boot-starter-web 2.3.1
- spring-webflux 5.2.7
- spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty 2.3.1

I'm trying to use `Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate` on websockets responses.
Netty supports websocket decompression since fix [507](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/commit/92a21f40869d3027d3ff4aaa4758e988aa16a272)  ([related question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53179626/spring-boot-2-webflux-websocket-activate-compression)

But it does not work (i.e, server does not use `permessage-deflate` proposed in request headers)

Whereas when I use **jetty** with `spring-boot-starter-jetty`, it works out of the box, no extra configuration needed.

Does anybody know how to resolve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the spring-webflux framework, the compression is disabled by default in the reactor-netty. Indeed the [default contructor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/socket/server/upgrade/ReactorNettyRequestUpgradeStrategy.html#ReactorNettyRequestUpgradeStrategy--) of class `ReactorNettyRequestUpgradeStrategy` create an instance of the class parameter value [WebsocketServerSpec with default value](https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/api/reactor/netty/http/server/WebsocketServerSpec.html) (compression = false).

[Reactor-netty](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/blob/89e6a4e8a696c8c1f73d2fe49d7a22fd21597f4b/reactor-netty-http/src/main/java/reactor/netty/http/client/HttpClientOperations.java) check the predicate `websocketClientSpec.compress()` to establish a compression support.

So the parameter `websocketClientSpec.compress` need to be activated.

```
@Bean
public WebSocketHandlerAdapter handlerAdapter(WebSocketService webSocketService) {
return new WebSocketHandlerAdapter(webSocketService);
}
@Bean
public WebSocketService webSocketService() {
return new HandshakeWebSocketService(
new ReactorNettyRequestUpgradeStrategy(WebsocketServerSpec.builder().compress(true)));
}
```

The result handshake :
[image]